# Find average of a column in a data set based on value of another column in R

Tags: r

I am trying to find the average age (the values in the first column) based on how many subjects are in the AD, MCI, and Normal columns in the data set below. Basically, I need the average age for subjects in the AD column, MCI column, and then the Normal column. Is there an R function that takes the average of another column based on the presence of a nonzero number in another column? Thanks!

```
  table(ADNI$AGE, ADNI$DX)
       AD MCI Normal
  55.6  1   0      0
  55.9  1   0      0
  56.2  2   1      0
  56.3  0   1      0
  57.8  3   1      0
  58.4  0   0      2
```

Comment: Looks like you need `aggregate(AGE ~ DX, ADNI, mean)`  The second part is not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't function that can do this but here's how you can solve your problem.

For the average age of AD `mean(data[,1] * data[,2])`

For the average age of MCI `mean(data[,1] * data[,3])`

For the average age of Normal `mean(data[,1] * data[,3])`

You don't have to worry about the zeros because when you multiply those ages aren't accounted for.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the dplyr package to do this.  The code below will group the data by DX then for each group sum the age and divide by the count for that age

```
library(dplyr)

ADNI %>% 
  group_by(DX) %>% 
  summarise(avg_age = sum(AGE)/n())
```